# If a thread interupts a spring transaction template mid execution is it guaranteed to roll back?

Tags: java, sql-server, spring

I have a thread that is executing a series of instructions, including sql updates against my database. I want to be able to protect the databases data integrity by enforcing a rollback if anything interrupts the threads execution while it's in the middle of the transaction template. An example of this threads exection is:

```
public void run() {
    executeStatements();
}

public void executeStatements() throws DataAccessException {
    return transactionTemplate.execute(new TransactionCallback<Long>() {
        public Long doInTransaction(TransactionStatus transactionStatus) {
            // series of statements
        }
    }
});
```

I've checked the docs but couldn't find anything the specifically said if this will be able to rollback the transaction, **even if the thread is interupted**?

Answer (score 2):

This is from my own experience as I too can't find a definitive answer, however, from experience if you spawn the thread before executing the transaction than yes, interrupting the thread would prevent the transaction from committing.  If the thread is spawned as part of the transaction than no, because the transactions handle would be on the other thread and depending on how you handle exceptions and thread interruption, the transaction could still commit.

Here's some light reading on the subject http://www.codingpedia.org/jhadesdev/how-does-spring-transactional-really-work/

So keep in mind that TransactionTemplate is the low-level access to transactions and aren't using the aspects `@Before` `@After` for `@Transactional` annotations.  It's up to you to manage that.  A `TransactionException` will occur when the transaction has been rolled back or some other system error occurs.  TransactionTemplate itself it completely thread-safe and doesn't create new threads.  It will bind anything it needs on the current thread upon calling `execute`.

Hope this helps.  I'll update the answer if I find more reading material.

Comment: Would he need a SQL database backup as well if the thread starting changing variables in the database?

Comment: the nature of a transaction prevents committing changes to the database upon errors and such so the only way values will be committed to the database is if the transaction succeeds, and only then.  Transactional models ensure that data persisted is data wanted and that no half-save's exist.  When a commit is made, that's when the data is finally persisted.

Comment: Okay, thanks, I'm not used to using the library so I wasn't sure how it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Interesting question. No definitive answer, just food for thoughts.

`TransactionTemplate.execute` will call `TransactionCallback.doInTransaction` wrapped in a try-catch-block. It will rollback the transaction if it catches an error or exception.

Now let's assume the thread which executes `TransactionCallback` is interrupted.

A rollback will only happen if the try-catch-block of `TransactionTemplate.execute` sees the `InterruptedException`.

To my understanding this can only happen if an operation in `TransactionCallback.doInTransaction` is **blocking**.

Since JDBC operations to a remote database block on socket IO this seems to be case, and therefore the rollback should be executed.